# Error en mi funcion de JS para aumentar Precio

Tags: javascript, php

tengo un problema con mi código, que debería de aumentar el precio según la cantidad se le esté dando, no obstante, cuando le aumento al imput, el precio sigue igual.
Este es el scritp que estoy usando

```
<script>
    function actualizaCantidad(cantidad, id){
        let url = 'Clases/Actualizar_Carrito.php'
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('id', id)
        formData.append('action', 'agregar')
        formData.append('cantidad', cantidad)

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            mode: 'cors'
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            if(data.ok){
                let divsubtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal_' + id)
                divsubtotal.innerHTML = data.sub
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Y este es el código de php que estoy usando para poder aumentar el número del precio, cuando ejecuto la página y le doy en aumentar, no se aumenta, y revisando en el apartado de red me sale ok:false, no estoy muy seguro del porque me sale así

```
<?php

require '../Config/Config.php';
require '../Config/DatabaseP.php';

if(isset($_POST['$action'])){

$action = $_POST['action'];
$id =isset( $_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : 0;

if($action == 'agregar'){
    $cantidad =isset( $_POST['cantidad']) ? $_POST['cantidad'] : 0;
    $respuesta = agregar($id, $cantidad);
    if($respuesta>0){
        $datos['ok'] = true;
    } else {
        $datos['ok'] = false;
    }
    $datos['sub'] = $respuesta;
} else {
    $datos['ok'] = false;
}
} else {
    $datos['ok'] = false; //Aquí es donde siempre me muestra que se queda
}

echo json_encode($datos);

function agregar($id, $cantidad){
$res = 0;

if($id > 0 && $cantidad > 0 && is_numeric(($cantidad))){
    if(isset($_SESSION['carrito']['productos'][$id])){
        $_SESSION['carrito']['productos'][$id] = $cantidad;

        $db = new Database();
        $con = $db->conectar();
        $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT Precio FROM producto WHERE ID=? AND Activo=1");
        $sql->execute([$id]);
        $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $Precio = $row['Precio'];
        $res = $cantidad * $Precio;

        return $res;
    }
} else {
    return $res;
}
}
?>
```

El html que estoy usando es el siguiente, la parte del script y el php ya están incorporados dentro del código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b8fe3f53d2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos/Estilo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos/CarritoList.css">
<title>Tienda Elva</title>   
  
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
    <div class="Tienda_logo">
        <a href="" class="logo">TIENDA ELVA</a>
    </div>

    <div class="contenier_bar">
        <div class="bar">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul class="nav-menu">
                    <li class="nav-menu-item"><a href="Index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-menu-item"><a href="Productos.php">Productos</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-menu-item"><a href="">
                        Carrito <span id="num_cart" class="badge bg-secondary"><?php echo $num_cart; ?></span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-menu-item"><a href="">Descuentos</a></li>

                    <div class="busqueda">
                        <input type="search" placeholder="¿Que desea buscar?">
                    </div>

                    <div class="user">

                        <!-- <a href="Registro.php" class="icono-user"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-large"></i></a> -->
                        
                        <?php 

                        error_reporting(0);
                        session_start();

                        $correo = $_SESSION['Correo'];
                    
                        if (empty($correo)) {
                            echo '<a href="Registro.php" class="icono-user"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-large"></i></a>';

                        } else {
                            echo '<a href="Registro.php" class="icono-user"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-large"></i></a>';
                            echo " $correo";
                        }

                        ?>

                    </div>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="contenedor-cart-list">
        
        <div class="table-prod">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>SubTotal</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                    if($lista_carrito == null){
                        echo '<tr><td colspan="5" class="text-center"><b>Lista Vacia</b></td></tr>';
                    } else {

                        $tota = 0;
                        foreach($lista_carrito as $producto){
                            $_id = $producto['ID'];
                            $_producto = $producto['Producto'];
                            $_precio = $producto['Precio'];
                            $_subtotal = $cantidad * $_precio;
                            $total += $_subtotal;
                        ?>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $_producto; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_precio; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" min="1" max="5" step="1" value="<?php echo $cantidad; ?>"
                            size=5 id="cantidad_<?php echo $_id;?>" onchange="actualizaCantidad(this.value, <?php echo $_id; ?>)">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="subtotal_<?php echo $_id; ?>" name="subtotal[]"><?php echo $_subtotal?></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" id="eliminar" class="eliminar" data-bs-id="<?php echo 
                            $_id; ?>" data-bs-toogle="modal" data-bs-target="eliminaModal">Eliminar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"></td>
                            <td colspan="1" >
                                <p class="total" id="total">Total:  <?php  echo $total; ?></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col envio">
                <button class="btn btn-envio">Realizar Pago</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pon tambien el HTML en la pregunta para que podamos comprobar los elementos con esos **id**, y también necesitamos ver como llamas a `actualizaCantidad(cantidad, id)` pues no se muestra en tu ejemplo, gracias.

Comment: no entiendo que hace ese signo **+** aquí:  `$action = $_POST['action+'];`  Supongo que ahí está el fallo (tipográfico), y de ahí el **false** en el siguiente condicional.,

Comment: Si fue error mío al copiar el código, igual no se actualiza el precio

Comment: Lo primero que deberías verificar es si los datos están llegando bien y se encuentran realmente en la superglobal `$_POST`. En mi caso, cuando he usado FormData, para encontrar los datos posteados debo hacer algo como esto: `$postData=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` y ahí sí tengo, en `$postData` lo que debería tener en `$_POST`. Por un motivo que desconozco, algunos servidores no te ponen los datos en `$_POST` cuando usas FormData, sino en el flujo de entrada de PHP.